# How to delete a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, visual-c++

I build an array with help with this question: [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)
Now, my question is, how do I delete it?
I know it's a `for` loop and then other delete, but I need help with details.

Comment: Hint: For every call to new, there should be a call to delete. Also, C++ have different operators for deleting arrays and deleting objects.

Comment: Stop using dynamic arrays, and start using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Hint: never ever use the keyword `delete`. Look up RAII

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/a/936709/1433901 ?

Comment: @MariusSiuram LOL!! Now I see, but here is much more clear!! From there I get confuse!!

Comment: @learnvst That's never use array new (and thus array delete).  You need `delete` for handling objects with arbitrary lifetime.  (And RAII has nothing to do with the issue.  As a general rule, if RAII can be used, you shouldn't be allocating dynamically to begin with.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you created it. If you have a 2D array, `yourArray`, that has `rows` number of rows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    delete [] yourArray[i];
}
delete [] yourArray;
```